# Utilização do método filter um array de objetos

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, filter

Tenho um array de objetos:

```
const musicData = [
    { artist: 'Adele', name: '25', sales: 1731000 },
    { artist: 'Drake', name: 'Views', sales: 1608000 },
    { artist: 'Beyonce', name: 'Lemonade', sales: 1554000 },
    { artist: 'Chris Stapleton', name: 'Traveller', sales: 1085000 },
    { artist: 'Pentatonix', name: 'A Pentatonix Christmas', sales: 904000 },
    { artist: 'Original Broadway Cast Recording', 
      name: 'Hamilton: An American Musical', sales: 820000 },
    { artist: 'Twenty One Pilots', name: 'Blurryface', sales: 738000 },
    { artist: 'Prince', name: 'The Very Best of Prince', sales: 668000 },
    { artist: 'Rihanna', name: 'Anti', sales: 603000 },
    { artist: 'Justin Bieber', name: 'Purpose', sales: 554000 }
];
```

Preciso filtrar apenas os nomes com mais de 10 caracteres e menos que 25. Fiz a seguinte lógica:

```
const results = musicData.filter((musicName) => {
  const {name} = musicName
  return name.length > 10 && name.length < 25
})

console.log(results);
```

Porém o retorno sempre é o array com os os objetos corretos, mas não apenas os nomes. Como posso fazer para que o valor de ***result*** seja apenas o array com os nomes e não o objeto inteiro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode encadear o `filter` com um `map`:

```js
const musicData = [
  { artist: 'Adele', name: '25', sales: 1731000 },
  { artist: 'Drake', name: 'Views', sales: 1608000 },
  { artist: 'Beyonce', name: 'Lemonade', sales: 1554000 },
  { artist: 'Chris Stapleton', name: 'Traveller', sales: 1085000 },
  { artist: 'Pentatonix', name: 'A Pentatonix Christmas', sales: 904000 },
  { artist: 'Original Broadway Cast Recording', 
    name: 'Hamilton: An American Musical', sales: 820000 },
  { artist: 'Twenty One Pilots', name: 'Blurryface', sales: 738000 },
  { artist: 'Prince', name: 'The Very Best of Prince', sales: 668000 },
  { artist: 'Rihanna', name: 'Anti', sales: 603000 },
  { artist: 'Justin Bieber', name: 'Purpose', sales: 554000 }
];

const results = musicData.filter(musicName => {
  const { name } = musicName
  return name.length > 10 && name.length < 25
}).map(musicName => musicName.name)

console.log(results)
```

Edit: o mesmo resultado com `reduce`, adaptado [dessa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34398453/9470114) resposta:

```
const result = musicData.reduce((res, musicName) => {
  const { name } = musicName
  if (name.length > 10 && name.length < 25) {
    res.push(name);
  }

  return res;
}, []);
```

Comment: Mas posso fazer sem o encadeamento? Usando apenas o filter?

Comment: Com uma função só, acho que não dê com `filter`, só com `reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando apenas o método [**`filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro)

```js
const musicData = [
  { artist: 'Adele', name: '25', sales: 1731000 },
  { artist: 'Drake', name: 'Views', sales: 1608000 },
  { artist: 'Beyonce', name: 'Lemonade', sales: 1554000 },
  { artist: 'Chris Stapleton', name: 'Traveller', sales: 1085000 },
  { artist: 'Pentatonix', name: 'A Pentatonix Christmas', sales: 904000 },
  { artist: 'Original Broadway Cast Recording', 
    name: 'Hamilton: An American Musical', sales: 820000 },
  { artist: 'Twenty One Pilots', name: 'Blurryface', sales: 738000 },
  { artist: 'Prince', name: 'The Very Best of Prince', sales: 668000 },
  { artist: 'Rihanna', name: 'Anti', sales: 603000 },
  { artist: 'Justin Bieber', name: 'Purpose', sales: 554000 }
];

// Utilizando apenas o método "filter"
const resultsFilter = [];
musicData.filter(music => (music.name.length > 10 && music.name.length < 25) && resultsFilter.push(music.name));
console.log('Utilizando "filter"', resultsFilter);
```

#### Referência

- [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro)

Comment: Mas a questão era pra uso do filter. Então não rolaria usar o forEach.

Comment: Veja que coloquei 3 exemplos, o ultimo é apenas utilizando `filter`